# Classification of albums as LPs and Playlists

Tags: album, spotify

[An LP is defined as a vinyl phonograph record played at 33 1/3 rpm and typically containing seven or more tracks, or one or more long classical pieces.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lp?s=t)

[A playlist is defined as an electronic file containing a list of audio or video files that can be played back on a media player sequentially or in random order.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/playlist?s=t)

Look at [a typlical Apple Music profile](https://music.apple.com/us/artist/selena-gomez/280215834). It classifies every album as "Albums", "Singles & EPs", and "Compilations".

Now look at a [typical Spotify profile](https://open.spotify.com/artist/0C8ZW7ezQVs4URX5aX7Kqx). It too classifies every album as "Albums", "Singles & EPs", and "Compilations".

But look at "Avril Lavigne".

According to the [Apple Music page](https://music.apple.com/us/artist/avril-lavigne/459885), her 2013 self-titled album is under "Complilations".

But this is incorrect, her 2013 self-titled album is not a compilation album. It is her sixth LP. [The spotify page](https://open.spotify.com/artist/0p4nmQO2msCgU4IF37Wi3j) correctly lists this album under "Albums".

In any case, nether Apple Music nor Spotify are reliable for this classification.

I didn't really understand why the Apple Music page and the Spotify page sometimes contradict each other this way.

Comment: And I asked a similar question in the Spanish site. https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/34822/colegio-and-dormitorio

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Streaming sites often get this kind of thing wrong. If they have some kind of way to  report errors, you can use it. Otherwise there's nothing much you can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Album is sort of a loose concept right now, but the problem you're probably noticing is that these allocations to categories are done via AI, which have different initial algorithms. How they "learn" to categorize may end up with different outcomes from time to time. It's the nature of the beast.